# Do I have to put the cover on the SSD when replacing the HDD?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive

I'm replacing my HDD with a SSD, and whilst I have the upgrade bundle kit, I'm gonna use my HDD as an external HDD. So, am wondering if I can leave that plastic cover (which is screwed to the HDD) or do I have to put it on the SSD?

edit: Now you can see on the image to what I'm refering as the "plastic cover".

[image]

Comment: That transparent film with the brackets on the side? I can’t imagine that doing anything particularly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only purpose of the cover is to make the HDD/SSD fit in the drive bay correctly. I imagine that you need to transfer the cover to the SSD, but it's not like anything bad will happen if you can fit the new SSD in the HDD slot without first moving the cover over.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: guys, thx for help - I just want to add that the HDD with this cover doesn't even fit in the "external HDD case", and IMO it's for easier "pulling out" of the laptops drive bay.